# how to configure terminal's size and location

Tags: command-line

I am running **Ubuntu precise**. I usually rely on the ALT-CTRL-T shortcut to open a new terminal. However the location is pops up as well as its size are not very convenient and I have to subsequently use the mouse to drag/resize the terminal. Is there a way to configure the terminal's initial size and location?

Comment: From what I know, there's a way to start the terminal maximized but IDK if there's a way to manually set x and y positions, I could be wrong,  though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I you right klick in your terminal window, select `Profiles > Default` profile. You should be able to edit your terminal's default size there.

To change the way new windowa appear, you should use `ccsm`.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run `ccsm`, scroll down to the plugin called "place windows" or something, click it and you'll get access to the settings.

Comment: Still works in Ubuntu 14.04 (at least for me).